Convert list of string column to numeric and summarize
I have a data frame where one column contains a string of numbers. Each row contains a set of numbers that vary in length. For example:
Month       Count
Jan         "[1.2445, 23.888883, 16.11208347]" 
Feb         "[2.6473, 400.6256]"
March       "[6723.1838282, 187.1212, 90.111, 75.1342899]" 

The goal is to convert the list into numeric format, and sum across each row. Resulting in something like (rounded decimals for ease):
Month       Count
Jan         41.245 
Feb         403.2729
March       7075.500 

I have used this code which works for a single row, but I am unable to abstract it over the entire data frame by row.
sum(as.numeric(strsplit(substr(Data$Count, 2, nchar(Data$Count) - 1), ',')[[1]]))


Please share your sample data using dput(head(Data, 3)).

Data <- read.table(text = 'Month       Count
Jan         "[1.2445, 23.888883, 16.11208347]" 
Feb         "[2.6473, 400.6256]"
March       "[6723.1838282, 187.1212, 90.111, 75.1342899]"', 
                   header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

Data %>% 
  mutate(Count = strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Count), ", ")) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_longer(Count) %>% 
  summarise(Count = sum(as.numeric(Count)), .by = Month) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

#>   Month      Count
#> 1   Jan   41.24547
#> 2   Feb  403.27290
#> 3 March 7075.55032

or
Data %>% 
  mutate(Count = purrr::map(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Count),
                                     ", "), 
                            ~sum(as.numeric(.x))))

Created on 2024-04-29 with reprex v2.0.2

make use of the jsonlite package:
transform(df, Count = sapply(Count, \(x)sum(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))))

  Month      Count
1   Jan   41.24547
2   Feb  403.27290
3 March 7075.55032


using py_eval from reticulate:
transform(df, Count = sapply(Count, \(x)sum(reticulate::py_eval(x))))
  Month      Count
1   Jan   41.24547
2   Feb  403.27290
3 March 7075.55032


You were almost there - in base R you can use lapply with your strsplit and gsub (instead of substr):
unlist(lapply(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", df$Count), ","), \(x) sum(as.numeric(x))))

# [1]   41.24547  403.27290 7075.55032

Data:
df <- read.table(text = 'Month       Count
                 Jan         "[1.2445, 23.888883, 16.11208347]" 
                 Feb         "[2.6473, 400.6256]"
                 March       "[6723.1838282, 187.1212, 90.111, 75.1342899]" ', h = TRUE)


Another option using parse_number
library(readr)

transform(df, Count = sapply(strsplit(Count, ", "), \(x) sum(parse_number(x))))
  Month      Count
1   Jan   41.24547
2   Feb  403.27290
3 March 7075.55032


Here is a base R approach where you convert the column into a sum expression to be evaluated (e.g. sum(1.2445, 23.888883, 16.11208347)):
df$Count <- sapply(parse(text = paste0("sum", chartr("[]", "()", df$Count))), eval)
#   Month      Count
# 1   Jan   41.24547
# 2   Feb  403.27290
# 3 March 7075.55032

